# Is there any way to run code coverage across multiple project in Emma?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, emma

I am using Emma Eclipse plugin to generate junit code coverage across multiple projects. Is there any way to generate reports for all the projects in a single go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found no way of running code coverage on all projects at a single go. But found a way to merge all the sessions in single and export the code coverage report. 
To merge the code coverage report you just need to go to 'Merge Sessions' from 'Code Violations' view in Eclipse.

Comment: there is also a merge button in the Coverage view in clipse.